# Javascript - regex - how to remove words with specified length

Tags: javascript, regex, words

In my case word length is "2" and I am using this regex:

```
text = text.replace(/\b[a-zA-ZΆ-ώἀ-ῼ]{2}\b/g, '') );
```

but cannot make it work with greek characters.
For your convenience here is a demo:

```js
text = 'English: the on in to of \n Greek: πως θα το πω';
text = text.replace(/\b[0-9a-zA-ZΆ-ώἀ-ῼ]{2}\b/g, '');
console.log(text);
```

As far as the greek characters are concerned, I try to use a range with 2 sets: "Greek and Coptic" and "Greek Extended" (as seen on [unicode-table.com](http://unicode-table.com)).

Comment: I was trying using unicode codes but with no lucky. I ended stuck in this `\u0391-\u03A9\u03B1-\u03c9`

Comment: Do you really need to use regex? With JavaScript code it´s easy to do this.

Comment: What is a: _"word"_? If it includes any char that is not `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, then those `\b` word boundaries will not work correctly.

Comment: I removed 0-9 from the regex, try to consider as word something which has only letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with greek characters is because of `\b`. You can take a look here: [Javascript - regex - word boundary (\b) issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23458872/javascript-regex-word-boundary-b-issue) where @Casimir et Hippolyte proposes the following solution:

> Since Javascript doesn't have the lookbehind feature and since word boundaries work only with members of the \w character class, the only way is to use groups (and capturing groups if you want to make a replacement):

```
//example to remove 2 letter words:
txt = txt.replace(/(^|[^a-zA-ZΆΈ-ώἀ-ῼ\n])([a-zA-ZΆΈ-ώἀ-ῼ]{2})(?![a-zA-ZΆΈ-ώἀ-ῼ])/gm, '\1');
```

I also added `0-9` inside the first and the third match because it was removing words like "2TB" or "mp3"

Answer (score 2):

Why using regex, I think you problem can be resolved without using regex

check the example below it should give you a hint on how to start

```
text = 'English: the on in to of \n Greek: πως θα το πω';
var tokens = text.split(/\s+/);
var text = tokens.filter(function(token){ return token.length > 2}).join(' ');
alert(text);
```

Comment: What about non alphanumerical bits, i.e. `--`, `..`, `?!`, etc.

Comment: the numbers are already included in the regex above `/\b[0-9a-zA-ZΆ-ώἀ-ῼ]{2}\b/g`, so it seems he need to remove them also, but a simple `parseInt` can solve the issue

Comment: @VisioN, yes this will trim the alphanum charachters, but I think the occurrence of these characters have a low priority, storing these characters in a dictionary, and skip them, is easier 100 times of using regex to handle unicode

Comment: Another problem is that characters like \t \r \n are removed.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has problems with Unicode support in regular expressions. To make the things working, I'd suggest to use [**XRegExp**](http://xregexp.com/) library, which has a stable support of Unicode.

**MORE:** http://xregexp.com/plugins/#unicode

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
text = 'English: the on in to of \n Greek: πως θα το πω';
text = text.replace(/\b[0-9a-zA-ZΆ-ώἀ-ῼ]{2}\b/g, '');
alert(text);
text2 = text.split(' ');
text = text2.filter(function(text2){ return text2.length != 2}).join(' ');
alert(text);
```

Edit-------------------

Try this,

```
text = 'English: the on in to of \n Greek: πως θα το πω';
text.replace(/\b[\n]\b/g, '\n ').replace(/\b[\t]\b/g, '\t ');
text2 = text.split(' ');
text = text2.filter(function(text2){ return text2.length != 2}).join(' ');
alert(text);
```

You will mantain \t, \n and will remove 2-letter word is between 2 tabs or two line feeds

Comment: Your approach doesn't delete tabs and line feeds (which is OK, I want this) but if a 2-letter word is between 2 tabs or two line feeds it's not removed.