# Regex match Arabic keyword

Tags: javascript, regex, arabic, arabic-support

I have simple regex which founds some word in text:

```
var patern = new RegExp("\bsomething\b", "gi");
```

This match word in text with spaces or punctuation around.

So it match:

```
I have something.
```

But doesn't match:

```
I havesomething.
```

what is fine and exactly what I need.

But I have issue with for example Arabic language. If I have regex:

```
var patern = new RegExp("\bرياضة\b", "gi");
```

and text:

```
رياضة أنا أحب رياضتي وأنا سعيد حقا هنا لها حبي
```

The keyword which I am looking for is at the end of the text.

But this doesn't work, it just doesn't find it.

It works if I remove `\b` from regex:

```
var patern = new RegExp("رياضة", "gi");
```

But that is now what I want, because I don't want to find it if it's part of another word like in english example above:

```
 I havesomething.
```

So I really have low knowledge about regex and if anyone can help me to work this with english and languages like arabic.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

We have first to understand what does `\b` mean:

> \b is an anchor that matches at a position that is called a "word boundary".

In your case, the word boundaries that you are looking for are not having other Arabic letters.

To match only Arabic letters in Regex, we use unicode:

```
[\u0621-\u064A]+
```

Or we can simply use Arabic letters directly

```
[ء-ي]+
```

The code above will match any Arabic letters. To make a word boundary out of it, we could simply reverse it on both sides:

```
[^ء-ي]ARABIC TEXT[^ء-ي]
```

The code above means: don't match any Arabic characters on either sides of an Arabic word which will work in your case.

Consider this example that you gave us which I modified a little bit:

```
 أنا أحب رياضتي رياض رياضة رياضيات وأنا سعيد حقا هنا
```

If we are trying to match only `رياض`, this word will make our search match also `رياضة`, `رياضيات`, and `رياضتي`. However, if we add the code above, the match will successfully be on `رياض` only.

```js
var x = " أنا أحب رياضتي رياض رياضة رياضيات وأنا سعيد حقا هنا ";
x = x.replace(/([^ء-ي]رياض[^ء-ي])/g, '<span style="color:red">$1</span>');
document.write (x);
```

If you would like to account for `أآإا` with one code, you could use something like this `[\u0622\u0623\u0625\u0627]` or simply list them all between square brackets `[أآإا]`. Here is a complete code

```js
var x = "أنا هنا وانا هناك .. آنا هنا وإنا هناك";
x = x.replace(/([أآإا]نا)/g, '<span style="color:red">$1</span>');
document.write (x);
```

**Note**: If you want to match every possible Arabic characters in Regex including all Arabic letters `أ ب ت ث ج`, all diacritics `َ ً ُ ٌ ِ ٍ ّ`, and all Arabic numbers `١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩٠`, use this regex:  `[،-٩]+`

Useful link about the ranking of Arabic characters in Unicode: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode

Comment: what will be the regex, if i want to use character list. like for word أنا, there can be multiple forms of أ or أإاآ

Comment: @FatimaZohra I updated my code to account for `أ أ إ ا`.

Comment: This only works if `رياض` is in the middle of the string (ie. if it has whitespace before and after), because `[^ء-ي]` needs to match something. How can we also match the word if it's right at the beginning and/or end of a string, as in `"رياض"`? We need to use groups that also match the beginning/end of a string, `/(^|[^\u0621-\u064A])رياض($|[^\u0621-\u064A])/g` or lookbehinds and lookaheads. `/(?<![\u0621-\u064A])رياض(?![\u0621-\u064A])/g` (But unfortunately lookbehinds are not supported in all browsers) (Also need to include punctuation - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/23481253/8620945)

Comment: What if I want to select a whole Arabic word and not just a letter

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work because of the Arabic language which isn't supported on the regex engine.
You could search for the unicode chars in the text ([Unicode ranges](http://kourge.net/projects/regexp-unicode-block)).

Or you could use [encoding](https://www.npmjs.com/package/encoding) to convert the text into unicode and then make somehow the regex (i never have tried this but it should work).

Answer (score 1):

I used this `ء-ي٠-٩` and it works for me

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a complicated RegEx (for instance, because you're looking for a particular word or a short list of words), then I've found that it's actually easier to tokenize the search text and find it that way:

```
    >>> text = 'رياضة أنا أحب رياضتي وأنا سعيد حقا هنا لها حبي '
    >>> tokens = text.split()
    >>> print(tokens)
    ['رياضة', 'أنا', 'أحب', 'رياضتي', 'وأنا', 'سعيد', 'حقا', 'هنا', 'لها', 'حبي']
    >>> search_words = ['رياضة', 'رياضت']    
    >>> found = [w for w in tokens if w in search_words]                                  
    >>> print(found) 
    ['رياضة']  # returns only full-word match
```

I'm sure that this is slower than RegEx, but not enough that I've ever noticed.

If your text had punctuation, you could do a more sophisticated tokenization (so it would find things like 'رياضة؟') using NLTK.