# regex in Arabic letters

Tags: javascript

In English it works well, but in Arabic I don't know why

```
const myText = "here";
console.log(/\bhere\b/.test(myText)); // true

// in Ar
const myText = "السلام";
console.log(/\bالسلام\b/.test(myText)); // false
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex match Arabic keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40731058/regex-match-arabic-keyword)

Answer (score 1):

Just use unicode entities:

```js
const myText = "السلام";
console.log(/\s*\u0627\u0644\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645\s*/.test(myText)); //true
```

Comment: How do I convert letter format?

Comment: You can use any online tool for encode/decode unicode text

Comment: The text is a variable that is not fixed

Comment: const myText = "السلام";
const validate = needle => (new RegExp('\\b' + needle + '\\b')).test(myText);
console.log(validate('السلام'));

Comment: I don't see why would the encoding changes anything, the point is that the word boundary mark (\b) only recognizes english. See the link on @clone 's comment above for possible alternatives.