# Using Regular Expression Find 0-360 in a String

Tags: regex

I want to write a regular expression which can extract the number between 0 to 360 in a string. Following are the example:

```
Text: "Rotate by 360 degrees"
OP: 360

Text: "36 degrees degree rotation"
OP: 36

Text: "rotate 100"
OP: 100

Text: "rotate 6700"
OP: NA (as 6700 is out of range)
```

I want to achieve it by regular expression

Answer (score 2):

Enumerate the possibilities:

```
\b([0-2]?[0-9]{1,2}|3[0-5][0-9]|360)\b
```

Answer (score 1):

#RegEx Number Range `[0-9]`
The [`\b` word boundary meta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23458918/2813224) is to ensure that words like: 36000 or l337 doesn't match. There are 3 [character class ranges](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)<sup>**†**</sup> (hundreds 1-2|3, tens 0-9|0-5, and ones 0-9). The `?` is a [lazy quantifier](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html) because the hundreds and tens aren't necessarily there all the time. The pipe `|` and surrounding parenthesis are [alternations](https://javascript.info/regexp-alternation) for 360 since the tens cannot be `[0-6]` because doing so leaves the possibility of matching 361 thru 369<sup>✱</sup>.

```
3[0-5][0-9] /* 300-359 */ |360 // 360
```

Although the possibility of exceeding 360 is prevented, so is the possibility of getting ranges of 160-199 and 260-299<sup>✱</sup>. We can add another alternation: `|` and change the ranges a little:

```
[1-2]?[0-9]?[0-9] // 0-299
```

- So to recap:
- `\b` keeps adjacent characters from bleeding into the matches
- `[`...`]` covers a range or a group of literal matches
- `?` makes the preceding match optional
- `(`...`|`...`)` is an OR gate

> ```
> \b([1-2]?[0-9]?[0-9]|3[0-5][0-9]|360)\b
> ```

<sup>**†**</sup>The equivalent for `[0-9]` as a meta sequence is [`\d`](https://help.relativity.com/9.3/Content/Relativity/Regular_expressions/Regular_expression_metacharacters.htm).

<sup>✱</sup>Thanks go out to  [Master Toto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/372239/toto) for pointing out the range flaws.

---

##Demo

```js
var str = `
Rotate by 360 degrees
36 degrees rotation
Rotate 100
Turn 3600
Rotate 6700
270Deg
0 origin
Do not exceed 361 degrees or over
Turn 180 degrees back
369 is also 9
00 is not a real number
010 is not a real number either
1, 20, 300, 99, and 45 should match because a comma: "," is a non-word character
`;

var rgx = /\b([1-3]0?[0-9]|[1-2]?[1-9]?[0-9]|3?[1-5]?[0-9]|360)\b/g;

var res = str.match(rgx, '$1');

console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Comment: This is matching `369`

Comment: Now, it doesn't match `180` ;(